# Heroku - How to fix "cannot load such file -- foreman/cli (LoadError)" ? - [Java, Windows, Ruby-on-rails]

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku, foreman

I'm following the official Heroku Java tutorial:

> [Getting Started with Java on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#introduction)

I've succesfully followed every step up to

> [Run the app locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#run-the-app-locally)

Running the command described in this step:

```
foreman start web
```

that on Windows needs to use a specific Procfile:

```
foreman start web -f Procfile.windows
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Andrea>foreman start web -f Procfile.windows
C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.r
b:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- foreman/cli (LoadError)
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/cus
tom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/foreman:8:in `<main>'
```

**What causes the problem, and how can I fix it ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that:

> **Foreman does not work if your installation of Heroku has any special characters or spaces in any directory name or in directory Hierarchy**

(thanks to [@theajaygupta](https://github.com/theajaygupta) for [finding the solution](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/520#issuecomment-118495933))

Since the **<kbd>[Heroku Toolbelt for Windows](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#set-up)</kbd>** installation is defaulting the Heroku path to

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku**

, everyone following the tutorial on Windows will get this error.

The solution is simple: **reinstall** the **<kbd>[Heroku Toolbelt for Windows](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-java#set-up)</kbd>** specifying a path without spaces and special characters. For example:

**Valid**

> - **C:\Heroku**
> - **C:\SeemsLegitIn2015\Heroku**

**Not Valid**

- **C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku**
- **C:\Progra~2\Heroku**

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @AndreaLigios for posting my solution on StackOverflow.

[@Gespejo](https://github.com/gespejo) is getting below problem taken from GitHub:

> I installed heroku in the c:\Heroku directory but it's still not working.  Can you help me? Thanks
>
> ```
> C:>foreman
> C:/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require': 
> cannot load such file -- foreman/cli(LoadError) from C:/Heroku/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
> site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_requi re.rb:36:inrequire' from C:/Heroku/bin/foreman:8:in
> ```

Follow the below Steps:

- Uninstall `Heroku Toolbelt` completely from your computer.
- Uninstall Foreman gem by using command `gem uninstall 'foreman'`.
- Now install `Heroku Toolbelt` again
- Check `foreman` is working now or not by running command `foreman` that will list all commands option supported by `foreman`

Let us know if problem has solved after executing above listed steps.